# Código JQuery apresenta resultado diferente dependendo do browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

Estou utilizando um
`<input type="datetime-local">` mas infelizmente não funciona no Mozilla.

Sendo assim pensei em implementar alguma coisa para mascarar esse problema, mas para isso eu preciso executar um código específico para o Mozilla.

Meu projeto utiliza `Jquery` e `Materialize` no Front-end.

Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podes sempre usar a data e o tempo em separado:

```html
<input type="date"/><input type="time">
```

Também podes brincar um bocadinho com o css para manipular as bordas

```css
input {  border: 1px solid; outline: none; }
.date { border-right: none; }
.time { border-left: none; }

div:hover input{
  border-color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div><input class="date" type="date"/><input class="time" type="time"></div>
```

Já que estas a usar jquery também podes embutir um plugin do jquery para te auxiliar

[DateTimePicker](https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)

```js
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/xdan/datetimepicker/master/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/xdan/datetimepicker/master/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css"/ >


<input id="datetimepicker" type="text" >
```

Comment: Eu preciso que seja apenas um campo mesmo...

Já tentei com o datetimepicker, só que quando clicava no campo abria apenas a janela com os botões, os dias não vinham

Comment: Eu tinha tentado com o datetimepicker sem sucesso, mas agora eu consegui!!!  Muito obrigado!

Comment: De nada, grato por ajudar